# Wpf Custom Media element

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mediaelement

Hey guys I'm fairly green when it comes to wpf, so I need a little help, here is what im looking to do.

I want to create a custom media element, I want to be able to load a video and play any where from 15 secs to 1 min of the video, I want to be able to dynamically set this on load up based on user settings. I'm loading tons of videos essentially into a list view control and I want the video to play, but im trying to save on resources by playing only a small preview of the video.

Things I've looked into

- custom control - somewhat lost
- subclassing
- pre build control

Im just really unsure on where to go next. I would greatly appericate any help you can give me.

Comment: Are you trying to build something that will download a preview video, and you'll handle an event to e.g. clear the window and download and play the full video?  Or something that will download the full video but play only a fragment at first (but has a way to play the full video)?  Or some intermediate behaviour?  There may be various ways to achieve what you want but it will depend on exactly how you want the custom element to work.

Comment: What I'm doing right now is looping through my video folder and adding media elements to a stackpanel which is in side of a scrollviewer. So i could have about 5-20 vids, I'm trying to build a kiosk app, so number of videos may vary. My initial thoughts is have the videos play between 15secs-1 min, looping. This way the user can knows its a video and not a picture (i have a separate scroll viewer for that). I'm really trying to cut back on resources this program will consume since hardware will vary. Trying to clip the vid it might not be the way to go, Idk, maybe better threading???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your comments expanding on the requirement, I'd suggest that you use the normal MediaElement, but assigning it a "preview" version of the video that only includes the fragment you want to show and has reduced resolution so as to keep load footprint down.

Thus, your model will have two properties, say PreviewUri and SourceUri.  At the PreviewUri, you store the "preview" version of the video; at the SourceUri, you store the "full" version.  In your ListBox or ItemsControl, you'll use MediaElements bound to the PreviewUri.  When the user makes a selection, you'll set the Source of the main MediaElement to the SourceUri.  So your ListBox will look something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <MediaElement Source="{Binding PreviewUri}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

your model will look something like this:

```
public class Video  // ideally implement INotifyPropertyChanged - not shown
{
  public Uri PreviewUri { get; set; }
  public Uri SourceUri { get; set; }

  public static ObservableCollection<Video> LoadVideoInfo()
  {
    /* pseudocode
    new up a collection
    foreach (file in videoFolder)
      collection.Add(new Video { PreviewUri = smallFileUri, SourceUri = bigFileUri });
    return collection;
    */
  }
}
```

and your code behind will look something like this:

```
DataContext = Video.LoadVideoInfo();
```

How you show the full-size video will depend on what you want to trigger this and where the full-size video displays.  Using a ListBox rather than looping and adding children to a StackPanel may help with this because you can use the SelectedItemChanged event, databind to SelectedItem or use the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property.

Comment: so does mediaElement object start its own thread? Because thats my other thoughts on improving playback.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how it manages threads internally.  But creating background threads yourself may be tricky because you can only interact with UI elements from the thread which owns them.  Also, the WPF media classes (MediaElement, MediaPlayer and MediaTimeline expose only a Source property of type Uri, so it's not obvious how you could load in data that you've asynchronously loaded yourself, short of creating a custom URI scheme or something.